# Change Text Font to Bold

Tags: sapui5

I have a table (`sap.m.Table`) and would like to change the header font to bold, but I'm unable to do that. Here is my code for one of the column definitions in my `*.view.xml`:

```xml
<Column xmlns="sap.m"
  hAlign="Left"
  width="17em"
>
  <Text text="Vendor" />
</Column>
```

After looking at the API (`sap.m.Text`), I don't see a way to change the text style and I'm also new to UI5. Could someone point me to where to look for this?

Comment: The question is lacking in details e.g. about the purpose of styling the header text in bold. It's unclear whether simply changing the theme to Horizon (which comes with default bold column header texts) is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

## sap.m.Label

Instead of `sap.m.Text`, you can use `sap.m.Label` which supports [`"Bold"` design](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.Label/preview).

```xml
<Column id="myColumn">
  <Label labelFor="myColumn"
    design="Bold"
    text="..."
    wrapping="true"
  />
</Column>
```

Additionally, enable the property `wrapping` (available since 1.50) in order to achieve the default behavior of `sap.m.Text`. Wrapping should be enabled for column headers as recommended by Fiori design guidelines:

> [*Column Headers - Best Practices*](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/responsive-table/#column-headers-best-practices)
> Use controls that wrap [...]. Do **not** use controls that truncate.

**Note:** If the label is not labeling anything, please try with [different controls like `sap.m.FormattedText`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54570363/5846045).

Answer (score 0):

## sap.m.FormattedText

Another option is to use `sap.m.FormattedText`<sup>[[api]](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.FormattedText/controlProperties)</sup> with an inline tag `<strong>` within the `htmlText` value.

```xml
<Column ...>
  <FormattedText htmlText="&lt;strong>My Column&lt;/strong>" />
</Column>
```

[image: sapui5 sap.m.Table bold column text]

### Note

1. In XML, the character `<` needs to be escaped with `&lt;`.
2. Browsers do **not** guarantee that the text within `<strong>` is always displayed in bold.

   > The `<strong>` element is for content that is of greater importance, while the `<b>` element is used to draw attention to text without indicating that it's more important. <sup>[[source]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong#%3Cb%3E_vs._%3Cstrong%3E)</sup>

   The element `<b>` is currently not supported by the `FormattedText`. On the other hand, `<em>` is supported to emphasize the text.

   > [image: strong and emphasized supported by UI5]

Answer (score 0):

I found by chance that using `<FormattedText>` instead of `<Text>` creates bold headers. This works without (!) using any additional bold or strong markup in the `htmlText` of  `<FormattedText>`.

So in your case you would go with:

```
<Column
  hAlign="Left"
  width="17em"
>
  <FormattedText htmlText="Vendor" />
</Column>
```

Whether this works seems to be somewhat dependent on the SAPUI5 version and the theme in use.
It works for me on SAPUI5 1.108 with the default theme (no `data-sap-ui-theme` specified in index.html).

Comment: The standard **bold** column header text comes from the "Horizon" theme (`sap_horizon` / `sap_horizon_dark`). Even without `<FormattedText>` but with a plain `<Text>` control, the column header text is bold in the Horizon theme: https://sdk.openui5.org/entity/sap.m.Table/sample/sap.m.sample.Table (Change the sample theme to "Morning Horizon" or "Evening Horizon").

Comment: The question itself is lacking in details e.g. about the purpose of styling the header text in bold. It's unclear whether simply changing the theme to Horizon is sufficient for the question author. Because I didn't want to encourage anti-patterns, I had deleted my past answers here, but I think we should delete this Q&A altogether. The question author hasn't been active in SO since 6 years..

Comment: SO is not primarily targeted at the questioner. Instead there are many others profiting from each q&a. It does not make sense to delete a whole thread simply because the OP is gone.

Answer (score -1):

Try like in the [Documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/723f4b2334e344c08269159797f6f796.html)

1. Create a custom CSS
2. Add your styleclass to the Control.